# A Segmented error occurred while I was using the pulseaudio API

Tags: c, api, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio

I had a segment error while running "[Sample Async Playback](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/Samples/AsyncPlayback/)" provided by "[pulseaudio](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/)"。 but my compilation passed.
[image]
Compile the way

```
gcc pa-beep.c -lpulse-simple -shared -fPIC -g
```

Here's Contains library files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pulse/pulseaudio.h>

static int latency = 20000; // start latency in micro seconds
static int sampleoffs = 0;
static short sampledata[300000];
static pa_buffer_attr bufattr;
static int underflows = 0;
static pa_sample_spec ss;
```

I added the print step inside the main function, and the result shows that the program did not execute this step.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("kai shi\n");
  pa_mainloop *pa_ml;
  pa_mainloop_api *pa_mlapi;
  pa_context *pa_ctx;
  pa_stream *playstream;
```

I'm sorry I'm a beginner. I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Segment error is a run time error not compile time error. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You forgot `#include <math.h>`. Try and report back and tell us what happened. This may or may not resolve your problem. BTW: when you see a warning containing the word "implicit declaration", consider it as an error.

Comment: Thank you. It's true that segmentation errors only occur when it's running. Doesn't the program start with the main function?It turns out that printf has a segment error before it even gets executed, and I'm confused

Comment: Please [edit]  your program and show a [mcve].

Comment: This is a good time to start learning to use a debugger. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems Try to run your program with `gdb` and see where and why it aborts. Remember to compile your program with debugging symbols (`-g`) to actually see something of your code.

Comment: Also `static short sampledata[300000];` might be a problem. Change temporarily to `static short sampledata[300];` and put `return 1;` right after `printf("kai shi\n");` and see if "kai shi" is displayed.

Comment: After the change, it is still not shown, and it is still a segmentation error

Comment: 而且我在虚拟机内运行此程序也是如此，同样第一步打印都没执行

Comment: Then it could be a problem with your platform. Does a a simple "Hello World" program run correctly?

Comment: 应该不是平台的问问题吧，我用VMware上的Ubuntu也是这个现象，，说实话，我很痛苦